# Custom constraint validator does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a custom constraint validator but I'm unable to get it working, here is the error I am having:

```
AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation  
"@Cmpny\MyBundle\Validator\IsGifImage" in property           
Cmpny\MyBundle\Entity\Post::$src does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

Here is the tree of my project:

```
src/Cmpny/MyBundle/Validator/
└── Constraint
    ├── isGifImage.php
    └── isGifImageValidator.php
```

isGifImage.php

```
<?php
namespace Appinest\WhenayBundle\Validator\Constraint;  
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**  
* @Annotation  
*/  
class IsGifImage extends Constraint¬
{
    public $message = 'This is not a gif image!';
}
?>
```

isGifImageValidator

```
  3 namespace Appinest\WhenayBundle\Validator\Constraint;¬
  2 ¬
  1 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;¬
  0 use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;¬
  1 ¬
  2 class IsGifImageValidator extends ConstraintValidator¬
  3 {¬
  4     public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint)¬
  5     {¬
  6         //My function
 22     }¬
    }
```

Then in my Entity Class I import:

```
use Cmpny\WhenayBundle\Validator\Constraint as CmpnyAssert;
```

And then use the assertion above what I want to validate:

```
@CmpnyAssert\IsGifImage()
```

I searched for solutions but found nothing about it, any help ? :/

Comment: DAMN IT DAMN IT DAMN ME !!! Thanks :) If you want, post your comment as an answer so that I can mark my question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought: rename your php scripts (camel-case) the first letter is lower-case 'is...' - it may expects the file to be named same as the class contained.